# How to creat a regex that matches everything exlude specific string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to creat a regex that gets a string, and matches the whole string except specific words.

For example the string:

"   boolean booleanic = true;"

I need the regex to match the whole string without the "boolean"
the regex should match the rest of the string right after the "bollean" (" booleanic = true;")

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: If your regex flavor supports lookbehinds, then you can do something like this: `(?<=\bboolean\b\s)(.*)` — [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aR4dA9)

Comment: Java. but it's ok if you give me the regular syntax of regex to test in regexpal.com

Comment: @Vipasana: Java or JavaScript? (regexpal.com works on JavaScript — Java and JavaScript are like car and carpet — they're not related.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one really easy way to `match the whole string without the "boolean"`. It doesn't involve regex and it works in just about any language or environment you might want to use.

Ready?

Search: `boolean`

Replace: `""` (empty string)

For instance, this will work in a text editor, or in a programming language with the appropriate replace function, probably something like `newstring = replace(oldstring, "boolean", "")`

Answer (score 0):

You need positive lookbehind.

```
(?<=boolean)(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kN4jA2)

Comment: does it works for this `foo boolean booleanic = true;` input?

Comment: Looks like yes. Check it out yourself.
http://regex101.com/r/fL5cA1
Or you need match "foo  booleanic = true;" ?

Comment: Why it fails to match `foo`? Op wants to match all the characters except `boolean`

Comment: FAIL? READ THE QUESTION:

the regex should match the rest of the string RIGHT AFTER the "bollean" (" booleanic = true;")

Comment: `I need the regex to match the whole string without the "boolean"` and also read the question title.

Comment: You're both right - the question is poorly defined.